# How to Store safely Mysql database credentials in my code

Tags: python, mysql, encryption, base64

```
try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',database='USER',user='root',password='password')
    sql_select_Query = "select * from AuthSys WHERE mac = '%s'"%mac
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql_select_Query)
    row_headers=[x[0] for x in cursor.description]
    records = cursor.fetchall()
except mysql.connector.Error as e:
    return [e]
finally:
    if connection.is_connected():
        connection.close()
        cursor.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

*I wanted to store the host='localhost',database='USER',user='root',password='password' securely in my python project.So that everyone whoever uses my script will not get access to my database*
**Note: I am new to stackoverflow.If i wrote something wrong please suggent me right.Thanks in Advance.**

Answer (score 1):

You should probably put the credentials in a separate config file that isn't deployed with the project. And pass the path of this file to the main entry of the application, something like this:

```
python main.py --config=/your-path/to/your-config-file.ini
```

You will also need to parse this --config argument and then read and parse the your-config-file.ini file.

Comment: They will also have the access the config-file ?Right?

Comment: set it on production. if anyone is using it locally they should set it the same way.

Comment: If you go this way, make sure you keep that config file **out** of any source control like github.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have too many such settings one common option is to get them from system environment variables.

```
user= os.environ["myuser"]
password= os.environ["mypassword"]
connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',database='USER',user=user,password=password)
```

See https://12factor.net/ factor 3.

I’d prefix all app settings environment names with something common, giving *bkapp_user*, *bkapp_password*.